# Android: Gridview cell size inconsistent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I want to achieve something like this[image]

but I have tried several ways by adjusting the layout_width, height of the image view, it still giving me inconsistent cell size [image]

Here is my code:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".STA" >

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#33b5e5"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

main activity.xml

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/photogridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"></GridView>
```

fragment_st_dummy.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

customitemview.xml

My question are:

1. If I want to have a fix height for the description panel, is it
   possible?
2. Is it a best practice to achieve gridview cell size consistency by fixing image size?

Comment: this is not your answer but if you want to acheive uneven grids check this out http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that is one of the problems with a GridView. If the items are not the same size, you will run into issues. The easy solution is to make them all a fixed size. You can look into the StaggeredGridView. There are a view opensource implementations of it, but I haven't tried any myself so I can't comment on them.